# Ruby on Rails - Adding a human security field into the simple_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a form created using the simple_form gem in Ruby on Rails but I would like to add a sort of 'What is 1+1?' question and input field as the last question to remove the risk of bots etc. How would I add this function into my form?

My form consists of the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @job, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
  <h2>Job Position:</h2>
    <%= form.input :position, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Job Position", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :company, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Company name", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :salary, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Salary", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :contract, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contract Type", label: false, collection: ['full time', 'part time', 'internship'], prompt: "Contract Type" %>
    <%= form.input :city, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "City", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :expirydate, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Expiry date", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :description, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Full job description", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :apply, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "How to apply", label: false %>
    <h2>Your Contact Details:</h2>
    <%= form.input :contactname, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contact Name", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :contactemail, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contact Email", label: false %>
    <%= form.input :contactphone, input_html: { maxlength: 60 }, placeholder: "Contact Telephone", label: false %>
    <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a validation to your model like this:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :human_sum 
  validate :not_a_bot

  private

  def not_a_bot
    if human_sum.to_i != 2 
      errors.add(:human_sum, 'Get out, you bot!') 
    end
  end
end
```

And then in your form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @job, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>   
  ...
  <%= form.input :human_sum, label: 'What is 1+1?'
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to add `:human_sum` to your permitted params in your controller as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be posting the post if you put in the correct answer of '2'?

I've put the first bit of code in job.rb underneath what I currently have and placed the form input into the form on new.html.erb which has created the field & if you put the incorrect number in then it doesn't post but likewise it doesn't post if you are indeed correct with the number '2'.

Comment: If you put the correct answer (``'2'``), then ``human_sum.to_i`` would be equal to ``2``, which in turn will not add any errors to the model and the validation will pass. The ``@job`` will not be saved in your controller and probably the user will be returned to the form view. If you need a different behavior please clarify.

Comment: If I put in an incorrect answer it doesn't show any errors. If the answer is correct I would like it to post the post and redirect to the index as my original code does and if it is unsuccessful then I would like it to stay on new.html.erb but with an error showing on the bot input field.

Comment: I updated my answer to put the error on the correct attribute (you'll not printing errors on ``:base``)

Comment: That is still not posting the post if the bot field is answered correctly and is showing the bot error even if the answer is correct

Comment: Are you using Strong Params? Did you add ``human_sum`` to the ``params.permit`` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70702/discussion-between-dgilperez-and-user2498890).